# Hacer update a registros de mensajes para marcarlos como leido

Tags: mysql

Tengo este proceso almacenado, necesito hacer varios update para marcar como leidos los mensajes. El problema es que solo se hace 1 update y quedan mensajes marcados como no leidos.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `ShowMSG`(IN `P_TO` INT, IN `P_FROM` INT)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE v2 INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE v3 INT DEFAULT 0;
        SET v1 := 0; 
        SET v3  := (SELECT COUNT(MSG_id) FROM tbl_msg INNER JOIN tbl_empleados ON tbl_empleados.EM_id = tbl_msg.MSG_who WHERE MSG_who != P_FROM AND MSG_read = 0);
        WHILE v1 < v3 DO
            SET v2 := (SELECT MSG_id FROM tbl_msg INNER JOIN tbl_empleados ON tbl_empleados.EM_id = tbl_msg.MSG_who WHERE MSG_who != P_FROM AND MSG_read = 0 LIMIT v1,1);
            UPDATE tbl_msg SET MSG_read = 1 WHERE MSG_id = v2;
            SET v1 := v1 + 1;
        END WHILE;

        SELECT MSG_id, MSG_from, MSG_to, MSG_msg, MSG_who, MSG_send FROM tbl_msg WHERE (MSG_to = @P_TO || MSG_to = P_FROM) AND (MSG_from = P_TO || MSG_from = P_FROM);
    END
```

Comment: ¿seleccionas mas de un mensaje para marcarlos como leídos? si no es así, la [respuesta del usuario Lamak](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/23038/78) te debería ayudar.

Comment: Sí, @Mauricio selecciono más de un mensaje para marcarlo como leído, esto debido en caso de que se acumulen varios mensajes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algún motivo en específico por el cuál estás haciendo el `UPDATE` fila por fila?. A menos que haya algúna restricción externa, deberías realizar estas operaciones como sets:

```
UPDATE tbl_msg m
INNER JOIN tbl_empleados e
    ON m.MSG_who = e.EM_id
    AND m. MSG_who != P_FROM 
    AND MSG_read = 0
SET MSG_read = 1
```

Comment: El update lo hago fila por fila, esto debido en caso de que se acumulen varios mensajes, @Lamak

Comment: @J.Tinajero No veo cómo eso puede implicar que lo hagas fila por fila. El código que mostré arriba los actualiza todos al mismo tiempo

Comment: ya utilice el código y funciono a la perfección. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Si actualizas fila por fila podrías generar algo así:

```
UPDATE tabla SET campo = '1' WHERE id_tabla in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
```

donde **in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)** contiene todas las id para actualizar